# Using hibernate on ejb 2.X

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jboss, ejb

I've created a simple application with ejb 2X and web module. App is packaged as EAR.
I want to test hibernate on ejb, but i have some problems testing on ejb-module. Test on web module works fine and I can do CRUD operations with hibernate.

The problem is when I try list from Table.

The method test on EJB throws Exception

**The code**

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
java.util.List list = session.createQuery("from DatosIsla").list();
```

**The Exception deploying app**

```
12:56:23,365 WARN  [EJBDeployer] Verify failed; continuing
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2395)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2519)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1406)
    at org.jboss.verifier.strategy.AbstractVerifier.hasEJBCreateMethod(AbstractVerifier.java:667)
    at org.jboss.verifier.strategy.EJBVerifier20.verifySessionBean(EJBVerifier20.java:1058)
    at org.jboss.verifier.strategy.EJBVerifier20.checkSession(EJBVerifier20.java:113)
    at org.jboss.verifier.BeanVerifier.verify(BeanVerifier.java:180)
    at org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer.create(EJBDeployer.java:515)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:795)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:787)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:652)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:184)
    at $Proxy7.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:316)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:472)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:213)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:286)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:968)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.start(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.InvokerAdaptorService.invoke(InvokerAdaptorService.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFactory.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:74)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:76)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:68)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:213)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:484)
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:149)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:466)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:707)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

If i comment third line app is deployed fine

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 //java.util.List list = session.createQuery("from DatosIsla").list();
```

Whats wrong?

I'm using 
eclipse helios
jboss 3.2.8
jboss-tools

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the hibernate libraries are not in the classpath of the application:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
```

Check in your project configuration and your launcher, that the hibernate jars are referenced. Same to the ear, are the jars included.
Also check that not multiple versions are deployed (from the application container as well as in the ear).